# I want to open dialog window to search for Excel file and import

Tags: vba

The following code will look for text files but I am looking to have the same dialog box pop up using the folder location of my current file. How would I do this?

fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

```
With Sheets("data export").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fName, _
    Destination:=Worksheets("data export").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = True
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "" & Chr(10) & ""
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Why does this code not work? It looks easier.                                                        Sub SelectFileGetAllSheetsSAS()
Dim ds As String
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
ds = ThisWorkbook.Name
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:= _
"Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Open")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath
Sheets.Copy after:=Workbooks(ds).Sheets("Master File")
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a dialog searching for your Excel files within a specified path using two approaches:

**1** - Using the GetOpenFilename and changing path with ChDir:

```
Dim file

'Set current path
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files, *.xls*")

If file <> False Then
 MsgBox file
End If
```

**2** - Using the FileDialog and setting the InitialFileName property:

```
Dim file As String, fd As FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then
        file = .SelectedItems(1)
        MsgBox file
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing
```

In both examples I've filtered all excel files, including the 2007 and earlier.